# Python: Handle digits followed by letters in variable names when using sympy.parsing.mathematica

Tags: python, sympy

I am using the tool `sympy.parsing.mathematica` to parse Mathematica expressions into python syntax. I would like to be able to handle variable names that contain digits followed by letters.

For example, when parsing the string `"1 + a23b + 4"` by calling `mathematica("1 + a23b")` I get the output `"a23*b + 1"`. How can I indicate that I want `"a23b"` to be treated as a single variable, so that the output in the above example becomes `"a23b + 1"` instead?

I tried passing a dictionary of the form `{'a23b':'a23b'}` by calling `mathematica("1 + a23b",{'a23b':'a23b'})`. However, this raises a `ValueError` with the following message `ValueError: 'a23b' function form is invalid.`.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SymPy 1.11 the `mathematica` parsing function is deprecated:

```
In [3]: from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica

In [4]: mathematica("1 + a23b")
<ipython-input-4-925ed25e63e8>:1: SymPyDeprecationWarning: 

The ``mathematica`` function for the Mathematica parser is now
deprecated. Use ``parse_mathematica`` instead.
The parameter ``additional_translation`` can be replaced by SymPy's
.replace( ) or .subs( ) methods on the output expression instead.

See https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/active-deprecations.html#mathematica-parser-new
for details.

This has been deprecated since SymPy version 1.11. It
will be removed in a future version of SymPy.

  mathematica("1 + a23b")
Out[4]: a₂₃⋅b + 1
```

Instead it is recommended to use the `parse_mathematica` function which handles this case in the way that you want it to:

```
In [5]: from sympy.parsing.mathematica import parse_mathematica

In [6]: parse_mathematica("1 + a23b")
Out[6]: a23b + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am running sympy 1.9, so I will have to wait to try your solution until I have updated my system.

I will hold off on accepting your answer to see if there is actually way to do it with the old parser.

Comment: Why not just install 1.11? The new `parse_mathematica` function is supposed to have a number of other improvements as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It seems that the latest sympy version I can get through anaconda is 1.10.1.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade sympy`